# Submit the button name by hitting the enter key on IE6

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-6

I have a problem on IE6 only.

I have a page with several forms, each contains a textbox and a submit button. As I'm using .NET MVC, I need the name of the submit button to execute the correct Action. When I'm hitting 'Enter' key, I have the same behaviour as a clicked action on Firefox or Chrome (Field and ButtonName is sent), but not in IE6, where I have only the field that sent.

So how to send the name of the button when I'm hitting 'Enter' key on IE6 ?

tl/dr : 
I need to send in POST this

```
Field=foo&Search=
```

by clicking the 'Enter' key on IE6 and not only

```
Field=foo
```

Chrome and Firefox works well by clicking or hitting 'Enter'

Thanks for helping :)

[EDIT] Add an example:

Source code

```
   <!-- gestion type operation -->
<fieldset>
    <legend>Interface de gestion des Types d'Opérations</legend>
    <% Html.BeginForm("TypeOperation", "Administration", FormMethod.Post); %>
    <%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.TypeOperationField)%>
    <input type="submit" id="RechercheTypeOperation" name="RechercheTypeOperation" value=""
        class="loupe" />
    <% Html.RenderPartial("ListeTypeOperation", Model); %>
    <% Html.EndForm(); %>
</fieldset>
<!-- gestion type operation -->
```

It is pretty simple, this form struct is repeated each time I need a search textbox + submit button in page.
Forms are well opened and closed when the code is generated.

Generated Code

```
    <!-- gestion type operation -->
<fieldset>
  <legend>Interface de gestion des Types d'Op&#233;rations</legend>
  <form action="/Administration/TypeOperation" id="form3"
  method="post">
    <input class="text-box single-line" id="TypeOperationField"
    name="TypeOperationField" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" id="RechercheTypeOperation"
    name="RechercheTypeOperation" value="" class="loupe" />
    <div>
      <table class="grid">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">//
<![CDATA[
if (!window.mvcClientValidationMetadata) { window.mvcClientValidationMetadata = []; }
window.mvcClientValidationMetadata.push({"Fields":[],"FormId":"form3","ReplaceValidationSummary":false});
//]]>
</script>
</fieldset>
<!-- gestion type operation -->
```

[EDIT 2] I have add this line inside my form

```
<!--[if IE]><input type="text" style="display: none;" name="RechercheTypeOperation" value="" disabled="disabled" size="1" /><![endif]-->
```

And it's working.

Comment: Please post your current code.

Comment: Please stop supporting IE6 (unless your boss requires you to do so and does not want to understand that IE6 needs to die ASAP)

Comment: Obviously, I don't have the choice to use IE6 :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you shouldn't rely on the name of submit button, but rather create an `<input type="hidden"` with the `name` you want (like `search`).

There's really no difference between submit button name and the name of any other input field, except that `submit` input field is not really a field, so there always could be some artifacts with that.

Comment: No, sorry I do when I'm using MVC and Attribute [AcceptButton("RechercheTypeOperation")] to validate my Action.

Comment: Okay, sorry. I really don't know anything about things in MVC, but as a bad workaround you can probably add hidden input when you see IE6 in User-Agent string.

Comment: I have add this line <!--[if IE]><input type="text" style="display: none;" name="RechercheTypeOperation" value="" disabled="disabled" size="1" /><![endif]--> and it is working ! Thank you :)

Comment: You can also try changing this input's type from `text` to `hidden`, this way you won't need `display:none` CSS.